# Shading issues with bevels on a cylinder

Tags: shaders, bevel

I'm having some issues with shading on a simple cylinder. When I add a bevel to the edge, it shows some unwanted lines in object mode. I just don"t know if this is something I shouldn't worry about, or if, most likely, I'm doing this the wrong way (as I'm new to blender). Shade smooth and auto smooth are on. I've tried the weight modifier as well but it gets worse actually.
Any help would be really appreciated, and I do hope this is not an issue that has already been resolved hundred times in this forum …
Thanks a lot for your help

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've extruded up the faces, bevel this edge:

[image]

Then you need to work with the knife to build this topology:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm really new to blender and honestly I don't see clearly for the moment how I can edit topology to get this result. But I'd like very much to learn and know! Could you please explain briefly how to get there? Thank you.

Comment: hard to explain in detail, I've edited my answer to show the beginning, once you've bevelled, the edge, use the knife to create the topology I show

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the geometry of the part facing outwards (away from the center), and so it's no longer consistent and shading issues appear. One way to produce a nice topology in such case is to just have a cylinder and **after** subdiv modifier shrinkwrap its top/bottom onto a profile:

1. Add a cylinder without caps, add a *Solidify* modifier and apply it. Duplicate the cylinder, name it `profile` and move up:

[image]

2. On the bottom cylinder add creases with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> like on the picture, add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, enable *Auto Smooth*:

[image]

3. Assign the top to a `shrinkwrap` vertex group:

[image]

4. Add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier projecting vertices from the `shrinkwrap` vertex group on the Z axis on the duplicated `profile` object:

[image]

The offset is there just to make it easier to see the effects of modifying the profile.

5. Modify the profile and bevel it like so:

[image]

(consider making the profile slightly thicker to be on the safe side)

### Beginner Friendly Version

1. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, Mesh, Cylinder, <kbd>F9</kbd> to open operator settings, decrease depth, disable filling. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to duplicate and limit movement to Z axis, to make sure it's exactly above. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> enter *Edit Mode* and <kbd>S</kbd> scale the cylinder down slightly (actually I scale it down quite a lot to make it more clear on the GIF). Then <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> go back to *Object Mode*, add a *Solidify* modifier to the bottom cylinder, with negative thickness to grow outside. Select the top cylinder, <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> go to  *Top Orthographic View* and add the *Solidify* modifier, make sure to set the thickness so that the outer side is definitely further away from the center than the outer side of the bottom cylinder (in this view it's easy):

[image]

---

2. With the top cylinder selected and your mouse over the modifier, <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to apply it, then with the mouse back in the 3D Viewport, <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> to go to *Edit Mode*, select two neighboring faces (you may need to press <kbd>3</kbd> to go to *Face Selection Mode*), <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd> to move those faces on Z axis (and move them down). Now, <kbd>2</kbd> for *Edge Selection Mode*, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button* on an edge to select an entire loop, and then <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button* on another edge to add another loop to the selection. Repeat the last step to select remaining loops you want to bevel, then press <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel those edges. Drag your mouse to control the amount of bevel - you may want to press <kbd>C</kbd> to limit the bevel, as well as you may want to scroll your $\color{#888}{█}\color{green}⬆\color{#888}{█}$ *mouse wheel up*, to increase the number of added segments for a smoother transition.

[image]

---

3. Once you're done with the profile (you can still edit it later), <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> to return to *Object Mode*, select the bottom cylinder, apply the *Solidify* modifier like in p. 2., <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> *Edit Mode*, <kbd>3</kbd> *Face Selection Mode*, click somewhere outside the mesh to deselect, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>$\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button* on an edge going from inside faces to outside faces of the top of the cylinder, then go to [image] *Object Data Properties*, and add a vertex group, name it `shrinkwrap`, and be sure to press *Assign* button to assign selected vertices to that group.

[image]

---

4. [image] In *Object Data Properties* scroll down and look for *Normals > Auto-smooth* - enable it. Deselect everything, <kbd>2</kbd> for *Edge Selection Mode*, select one of the edges being a part of a circle, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to *Select Similar*, and choose <kbd>F</kbd> *Face angles*. Now <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to *Crease*, and <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>↩ Enter</kbd> to set full crease on those edges. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd> to go to *Object Mode*, and <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> to add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier lvl 3.

[image]

5. Add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier. As a target choose the top cylinder, as a method *Project*, as axis **Z**, and remember to use the `shrinkwrap` vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this looks very very interesting. I'm going to try that and I'll get back to you when I'm done. Thanks again for taking the time to answer this with detailed info.

Comment: I've been working on your solution and arrived at your last advice : (consider making the profile slightly thicker to be on the safe side). But as I've applied the Solidify modifier on both cylinder,(step 1) I'm wondering if I still can increase the thickness of the top cylinder (profile) or if it's too late and should start again from the beginning … Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, I've been trying your solution several times but can't reach your result… There must be something wrong in the way I do this but can't figure that out. Unfortunately. Although shrinkwrap works, the bottom cylinder keeps its outer faces. Must be something to do with the thickness of the top cylinder I guess, but not sure. I don't want to take too much of your time, but I'll share the file if you're ok to have a look at it. Thanks for helping. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gEnMgJQA" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gEnMgJQA/)

Comment: @hhuchon the best way to make one cylinder slightly thicker would be to spawn a slightly smaller cylinder so the inner faces are closer to the center, and add enough thickness in the solidify modifier to make the outer faces further from the center.

Comment: Having issues doing this … 
Are the creases from step 2 necessary?
What kind of settings should I use for the subdiv mod?
Step 3: the shrinkwrap vertex group belongs to the bottom cylinder? Not the top one?
Step 4: I have to apply the shrinkwrap modifier on the bottom cylinder, not the top one?
Step 5: your modifying (grab z I guess) the top cylinder, not the bottom one?
Honestly I've been trying your solution for hours, still can't make this works, it's driving me mad! Looks straight forward from your explanations, there must be something I'm missing.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @hhuchon see edit.

Comment: One word: Alleluia! Now that I understand the principle and the technique to get there, I'll try to create the exact object I need, that's another step. I''m working on this since several days, watched hours of tutos online, searched for a solution using boolean cuts, topology editing (which I think is a region definitely worth exploring and mastering), data transfer, all this to try to get the perfect shading. I'm not sure that small issues with shading will show after render, but seems clear that perfecting and understanding things has benefits. Thank you very much for your work and help.