# how to get better topology modelling PlayStation mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying to model the PlayStation. I'd like to know how to get those semi circle curves on the model indicated in red outline. I tried Boolean and also with sub modifier but getting bad results.

[image]

Comment: the last picture is not so bad, why are you not glad with this topology?

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to get the ridges correct. So I tried with Booleans and became messy topology. Is Boolean ok to model something like this? Because since the topology lines is making circle shapes on the mesh, I have to straighten out the lines. 

https://ibb.co/561tvkK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a blueprint. Draw the main lines from the top view:

[image]

Then from the front view, extrude up:

[image]

Select these faces:

[image]

Extrude them up:

[image]

Create the details if necessary (you could also draw them at the beginning):

[image]

Comment: I think the most important part here is the polar coordinates of both vertices making the circle, and vertices of geometry that "hugs" the circle, are the same, because they come from the same original circle. This way they will consistently subdivide into the same shape - just with an offset.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar to this answer:

[Shading issues with bevels on a cylinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/265872/60486)

[image]

I used solidify on a copy of the cylinder rather than just using offset, because I wanted the offset to be equal along the surface normal, rather than along the projection axis Y.

Comment: Thanks for your information, always helpful insight!

Kind regards.